# How to attach the Eclipse debugger to a python program started from a script?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm using Pydev. I want to debug a python program that starts from a bash script called `runanki`, which is just like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/share/anki")
import aqt
aqt.run()
```

When I tried to debug the program, Eclipse seemed to be looking for the `main` method, which was futile, of course. So how can I tell Eclipse it could start the program just by executing `runanki`?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create a Python entry point to your program, rather than trying to mix in a bash script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, this is very short and full of python script, creating a python entry point would work. I'm just curious if I really have a project starting from a bash script, is it possible to direct Eclipse to start it using another program, and follow it into the python project?